# The question about use the marker in react-native-maps

Tags: marker, react-native-maps

I am working on a react-native app development. I set two screen, the main screen with a map and some markers in the map which show the different communities. Another screen will show some data in this community.

My question is when I click the marker on the map of main page. I want it to navigate to the specific second screen. I want to transfer the location data, which includes the longitude and latitude from the marker to the second screen.

Is someone know how to achieve it?

Comment: What are you using for navigation between views ?